# Why awk fails opearating on decimal point numbers?

Tags: awk, integer-arithmetic

To find the difference between two values, I used the command below

```
awk -v n1="1581097198.000749862" -v n2="1581097198.000449861" 'BEGIN{printf ("%.9f\n",n1-n2)}'
```

Output I get using the above command: `0.000299931`

But it is wrong, the correct value is `.000300001`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Most likely, the only thing your'e doing wrong is expecting perfect accuracy in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: The canonical for that is [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 3):

Using the wrong tool for the job.

```
echo "1581097198.000749862 - 1581097198.000449861" | bc -l
.000300001
```

If you want to modify the formatting you can always pipe the output from `bc` through `awk`.

Comment: ...because all numbers in `awk` are floating point and so affected by floating point math considerations while `bc` never uses floating point but uses fixed precision decimal numbers instead.

Answer (score 1):

`bc` is absolutely a great tool for this job. It is automatically [arbitrary precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) and the gotchas with floating point are avoided.

There are a couple of alternates to `bc` to consider.

You can use GNU awk if it was compiled with the MPFR library. You need to [set the precision](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Setting-precision.html) to something more than the default 53 bits. In this case, quad precision or 128 bits is fine:

```
n1="1581097198.000749862"
n2="1581097198.000449861"  

gawk -M -v PREC='quad' -v n1="$n1" -v n2="$n2" 'BEGIN{printf ("%.10f\n",n1-n2)}'
0.0003000010
```

The advantage with `gawk` is it is likely faster with a fixed word size floating point vs most arbitrary precision methods. They can be orders of magnitude slower.

You can also use `perl` with `bignum`:

```
echo "$n1 $n2" | perl -Mbignum -lanE 'say $F[0]+0.0 - $F[1]'
0.000300001
```

(The `$F[0]+0.0` just tells Perl to treat `$F[0]` as number which then triggers the conversion to a bignum)